# How to deal with `cannot pull system configurations` error in cluster deployment of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I deployed a cluster version of Apache IoTDB and the system popped out an error, the information was `ERROR o.a.i.db.service.DataNode: 258 - Cannot pull system configurations from ConfigNode-leader after 10 retries`. Does anyone know what this error means and how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ConfigNode in Apache IoTDB has failed to start. You can check whether the ports starting with `cn` (which means ConfigNode) are already occupied, and switch these occupied ports to solve this error.